# TypeScript React помогите типизировать компонент в HOC в route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

Я сделал обёртку для формы, которая в зависимости от роута передает в форму разные колбэки, на создание и на обновление сущности, но когда я вызываю этот HOC в роуте и передаю ему компонент формы, ts ругается на типизацию оборачиваемого компонента

Код обертки

```
type ComponentProps<EditEnity, CreateEntity> = {
  callback: (task: EditEnity | CreateEntity) => Promise<void>
}

type Props<EditEnity, CreateEntity, ServiceType> = {
  Component: React.ComponentClass<ComponentProps<EditEnity, CreateEntity>>
  service: ServiceType
} & RouteComponentProps<RouteParams>

type RouteParams = {
  taskId: string
}

function FormWrapper<EditEnity extends BaseEntity, CreateEntity, ServiceType extends RestPaginationService<EditEnity, CreateEntity> = RestPaginationService<EditEnity, CreateEntity>>({
  Component,
  service,
  ...props
}: Props<EditEnity, CreateEntity, ServiceType>) {
  const isTaskToEdit = (taskEntity: EditEnity | CreateEntity): taskEntity is EditEnity => {
    return (taskEntity as EditEnity).id !== undefined
  }

  const submitHandler = (taskEntity: EditEnity | CreateEntity) => {
    if (isTaskToEdit(taskEntity)) {
      return service.update(taskEntity)
    }
    return service.add(taskEntity as CreateEntity)
  }
  return <Component {...props} callback={submitHandler} />
}

const CustomFormWrapper = <EditEnity, CreateEntity>() => FormWrapper
export default CustomFormWrapper
```

Вызываю его в роуте

```
<Route
          path="/admin/tasks/ordering/add"
          exact
          //@ts-ignore
          render={props => <CustomFormComponent {...props} service={service} Component={OrderingTaskForm} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/admin/tasks/ordering/edit/:taskId"
          exact
          //@ts-ignore
          render={props => <CustomFormComponent {...props} service={service} Component={OrderingTaskForm} />}
        />
```

[image: Вот такая ошибка]

если поставлю any в типе оборачиваемого компонента ошибки нет

```
type Props<EditEnity, CreateEntity, ServiceType> = {
  Component: React.ComponentClass<any>
  service: ServiceType
} & RouteComponentProps<RouteParams>
```

Буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 1):

Я не понимаю полную идею кода, вот пример HOC в связке с react-roter

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useRouteMatch,
} from "react-router-dom";
import type { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

interface DefaultComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
  handler: () => void;
  service: Object;
}

const DefaultComponent = (props: DefaultComponentProps) => {
  const { handler } = props;
  return <button onClick={handler}>click</button>;
};

const ContentHOC = (props: Omit<DefaultComponentProps, "handler">) => {
  const {
    params: { id },
  } = (useRouteMatch("/:id") ?? { params: { id: null } }) as {
    params: { id: string | null };
  };
  const callback = useCallback(() => {
    if (id === null) return alert("Home page");

    alert("any page");
  }, [id]);

  return <DefaultComponent {...props} handler={callback} />;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <header className="App-header">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </header>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              render={(props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => (
                <ContentHOC {...props} service={{}} />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/about"
              render={(props) => <ContentHOC {...props} service={{}} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: у сделал в итоге сам